# Error: Expected private key to be an Uint8Array with length 32

Tags: blockchain, solidity, web3js, hardhat

Following the guide from https://ethereum.org/vi/developers/tutorials/hello-world-smart-contract/

I am getting this error when trying to run my deploy script. I am absolutely lost as to why this is not working as I have copied every piece of code directly from the guide.

**My hardhat.config.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();

require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

/**
* @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
*/
module.exports = {
   solidity: "0.7.3",
   defaultNetwork: "ropsten",
   networks: {
      hardhat: {},
      ropsten: {
         url: API_URL,
         accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
      }
   },
}
```

**My deploy.js**

```
async function main() {
    const HelloWorld = await ethers.getContractFactory("HelloWorld");
 
    // Start deployment, returning a promise that resolves to a contract object
    const hello_world = await HelloWorld.deploy("Hello World!");
    console.log("Contract deployed to address:", hello_world.address);}
 
 main()
   .then(() => process.exit(0))
   .catch(error => {
     console.error(error);
     process.exit(1);
   });
```

**my .env**

```
API_URL = "https://eth-ropsten.alchemyapi.io/v2/[REDACTED]"
PRIVATE_KEY = "[REDACTED]".  // my private key goes here, not including the 0x
```

It compiles fine but gives me the error when I use the command

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network ropsten
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the 0x in the private key, just put the exact key you got from metamask :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx

As per usage example we need to add chain name while creating Transaction.

```
const tx = new Tx(txObject , { chain: 'rinkeby' })
```